# Add legends manually for graphic layer in arcgis javascript

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

In my arcgis map application I am adding legends for featurelayer like this

```
legendLayers.push({ layer: singleCityLayerFeature, title: cityLayers[i][1] });
```

This adds legends for that "CityLayer". FeatureLayer which I am using already have legends.

But I also have creating graphic layers which has different icons for graphics. How do I add these icons in legends with title just like legends added for feature layer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create legends for GraphicLayers. The documentation clearly states which layers are supported.

> The legend supports the following layer types:
>   ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer,
>   FeatureLayer, CSVLayer, KMLLayer, and WMSLayer.